# Does Erlang Have Access to Public Key Sent to ssh:daemon?

Tags: ssh, erlang

In using erlang's ssh:daemon with a custom shell, is there a method to access the public key sent from a remote client? I would like to use the key for further authentication in commands later executed in the shell, but do not see a way how.

Comment: The environment where this is running is currently using Erlang/OTP R14B04, but if this requires a newer release an upgrade would definitely be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe erlang's **ssh** module does not expose raw public keys to it's public API, but if you really need 'em you probably can succeed in digging this out of [ssh_transport.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/ssh/src/ssh_transport.erl), which is almost undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

As of Erlang OTP 20 there's a documented `key_cb` option for `ssh:daemon()` family of functions, which allows to pass a function handling the key.